# Prolog: Getting predicate solutions and asserting them as facts

Tags: prolog

I've got a specific problem but I'll just try and come up with a general question so other people might benefit from it too...

I've got a predicate that returns many solutions i.e.

`X=5;`
`X=2;`
`X=7`

and I want a predicate that gets each of these solutions and asserts them as Prolog facts then so I end up with three facts in this case e.g.

`fact(5)`
`fact(2)`
`fact(7)`

so calling `fact(5)` would be true but calling `fact(8)` would be false because we never asserted it because it wasn't a solution.

But I don't want to have a predicate where you have to keep asking for solutions to assert each single fact.  I want to call a predicate and have it go through all the solutions in the background, assert them and that's it.

One way of solving it is using findall to put all the solutions into a list and then just go through the list asserting each element of the list.  However, I don't think this is very elegant.  There must be a nicer way of doing it without fiddling around with lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a failure-driven loop to force backtracking over all solutions:

```
?- computation(X), false.
```

You can ignore this query's declaratively false truth value with ignore/1:

```
?- ignore((computation(X),false)).
```

Comment: Hey Mat, cheers for this.  This works :).  I'll have to admit I'm not entirely sure how though?  I know I'm being fussy but I'm not so sure about the ignore predicate but I'm certainly not complaining thank you.  I'll go away and think about this and mark this as solved when I see what's going on.

Comment: +1. @shuyin - This works because `computation/1` leaves choice-points (alternative options) which Prolog will backtrack to execute every time it comes across the `false` after successfully executing `computation/1` (hence, _failure-driven_). This requires that `computation/1` performs the `assert` of a solution, which is not retracted (or undone) on failure/backtracking. Once all choices are exhausted and asserted, Prolog has no choice but to execute `false`, resulting in failure, but is rectified by ignoring the result using `ignore/1` as shown.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality can be made using setof and making a second order predicate.

```
:- dynamic fact/1.

isAns(5).
isAns(2).
isAns(7).

computation(F) :- setof(X,call(F,X),S),factify(S).

factify([X|Xs]) :- assert(fact(X)),factify(Xs).
factify([]).
```

Then when we go and ask about facts we get:

```
computation(isAns), fact(X).
X = 5;
X = 2;
X = 7;
false
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this.  However, there is an important difference in what I'm struggling with here.  You have some facts already - the isAns/1 facts.  Then you're just checking to see if an integer is fact and then asserting this fact in a different thing i.e. fact/1.  So if I ask `:- computation(X)` then I get `X=5;2;7;false` but what I want is something that does `computation(X)` and returns `true` but what it has done is asserted all of my facts i.e. X being equal to 5,2 and 7 but hasn't required me to keep 'pressing ';'' if you get me :)

Comment: Hope that clarifies my question :D

Comment: @shuyin, I adjusted my answer to better match your question. I totally misinterpreted your question =D. I hope this is what you want.