# prolog predicate returns facts(?)

Tags: list, prolog

First of all, if the answer to my question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296687/prolog-getting-predicate-solutions-and-asserting-them-as-facts) or [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ais/Prolog/search.html)
I couldn't find it so please don't kill me.

I want to write a Prolog predicate which returns a list of this form:

```
(list[elem, elem2], list[elem3, elem4], list[elem5, elem6]).
```

now I can think of several ways to return a list of this form:

```
([elem, elem2], [elem3, elem4],[elem5, elem6]).
```

but how do I make the word "list" appear there as well? what is it even? a fact? another predicate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow where we don't kill OP.

Comment: Why do you need the word "list" to designate the lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a compound term using the standard `=../3` built-in predicate. For example:

```
| ?- Term =.. [list, [1,2,3]].

Term = list([1,2,3])
yes
```

But note that the syntax that you're trying to use, `list[elem5, elem6]`, is not valid. Are you trying to mimic an *array* representation? If so, maybe use instead `list(elem5, elem6)`? For example:

```
| ?- Term =.. [list, elem5, elem6].

Term = list(elem5, elem6)
yes
```